# Unity3D Console Warning: Not derived from MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C#, and I'm trying to understand this console warning.  This is a simple class I'm storing some data inside. Am I using elements from MonoBehaviour?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TileType {

    public string name;
    public GameObject tileVisualPrefab;
}
```

Comment: How do you use this class ? Having a simple class like this one is possible in Unity, but you can't attach it as a component of a GameObject (using gameObject.AddComponent)

Comment: remove unityEngine namespace

Answer (score 0):

When attaching scripts to game objects they must inherit from monobehaviour. If a property of that class is a simple c# class like your example then that will be fine, it would not need to inherit from mono.